# Django QuerySet best practice

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there any better way to do this

```
us = User.objects.filter(id=someid)
if us.exists():
   u = us[0]
```

As I see in the sql log, us.exists() will execute a sql query, then u = us[0] will execute another query. So we have to do 2 query to get thing done. I just want to ask for a better way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.get()` does not make use of django queryset caching. So if you are really want to use and reuse the queryset, better way would be to catch `IndexError` like:

```
us = User.objects.filter(id=someid)
try:
   u = us[0]
except IndexError:
    #item does not exist.
```

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu that's nice to know!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `id` is unique, you should probably ask forgiveness, not permission:

```
try:
    u = User.objects.get(id=someid)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # do whatever you should do if user does not exist
```